# How to hide a series from MS Excel chart data table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

> **How can I hide *Series 3* from the below chart data table?**

I want to show the series (i.e. *Series 3*) in the chart, but hide it from the *chart data table*.

[image]

Comment: Can you just hide ROW 18?

Comment: I doubt it's possible to achieve what you're asking for. You could perhaps create a white box to cover that part of the data table.

Comment: What happens if you hide column D?

Answer (score 3):

Please check whether my suggestion is helpful.

Choose cells of Series 3 from data source > Format Cells > Custom >  Enter **;;;** (three semicolons) as the format > Press OK. Then data would be invisible in data source and data table, but still show in the chart.

[image]

[image]

----------- Update ------------

If you want to hide the tag of "Series 3", you may also format the **;;;** for title "Series 3" in data source. Then choose "No Legend Keys" for data table.

*But please note, under this case, the words "Series 3" for Legend will be also hidden.*

Or you can consider my previous suggestion above, keep the tags of Series 1, Series 2, Series 3 with legend keys, which will be displayed as "Legend", besides, untick the box "Legend" for this chart.

[image]

Comment: But what about the tag *Series 3*? How to get rid of that thing from *Chart Data Table*??